# Cross Domain jQuery Ajax Get Request that Ignores Response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm making a web service call using jQuery's $.ajax to a server on a different domain which I do not control. Unfortunately, the server responds with JSON, not JSONP. So I get `Unexpected Token :` error when my callback tries to execute the JSON without a callback "padding" it( JSON by itself is not valid Javascript).

I want to know if there's a way to use $.ajax to make a cross-domain GET request and ignore the response. I really only need one-way communication here.

Code snippet:

```
$.ajax( 
{
    url: 'http://service.somedomainidontcontrol.com',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(){
      e_log("Success");
    },
    data: my_data
  }
);
```

Server Response(which I would like to ignore):

```
{"status":"success"}
```

It occurred to me that I could perhaps append an iFrame to the DOM to accomplish this but I really want a cleaner solution. Also, I'd prefer not to rely on another server to proxy the request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do I understand you correctly, that you want to send a request to a server you don't control, but don't care if you get a response?

If that is the case, you can create an image in javascript and use the server address as its source:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://service.somedomainidontcontrol.com';
```

As soon as you add the `src` to the image, it will fire of a request to the server.  You will get a response that doesn't make any sense as an image, but who cares. :)

Comment: Brilliant! What a simple and clean solution. I've tested and it does exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: This is an eye opener for me! I can use this in lot of places. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**.  This is old, but I wanted to point out for others finding this that for the img solution - this is no longer "asynchronous".  What that means is that if the server is slow in responding, *you can delay your page load time*.

If you use the img tag solution, be sure to hook it to page complete or take other steps to not impact site performance.